# Перестал работать console.log

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Пишу пет-проект на react/reduxtolkit и в один прекрасный момент перестал работать console.log - от слова совсем. В логах никак не отображается. Ни в компонентах, ни в обработчиках событий. Пробовал запустить прошлый коммит - та же проблема. Ума не приложу с чем это может быть связанно. Пожалуйста помогите.

Проблема оказалась более глобальной изменения в любых файлах кода перестали отображаться после запуска приложения как динамически так и после запуска командой `Npm start`.
В приложении скрин с примером - чтобы этот код скомпилировался и в терминале высветилась ошибка нужно коммитить  изменения в гид хаб. Как это можно изменить? Заранее спасибо
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если написать `console.log` в `index.html` или в корневом `JS` файле, то тоже не сработает? А в консоли браузера работает?

Comment: Попробуйте открыть в другом браузере. Если проблемы в другом браузере нет, то, возможно, у вас включены какие-то фильры в разделе `Console` `DevTools`

Comment: В браузере  "console.log(1)" - undefined. А вообще пробовал все файлы реакции никакой.

Comment: попробовал через Firefox - результат такой же

Comment: У вас где-то определена переменная с именем `console`. Поищите по коду.

Comment: Может какой-то линтер убирает все консоль логи? Работают ли `console.error` и `console.info`?

Comment: Проблема оказалась более глобальной, у меня вообще не вносятся никакие изменения в проекте. Ошибки в том числе. Только после комминта и пуша на git компилятор начнает работать